# Evaluate jQuery code nested in the object when object is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS object like:

```
{
  'element1': {
    'redirectURI': 'abc.php?toDate=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.dateField1').val())
  },
  'element2': {
    'redirectURI': 'pqr.php?&toDate=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.dateField2').val())
  }
};
```

I need the **redirectURI** index to be evaluated when the object is used i.e. when `obj['element1']['redirectURI']` or `obj['element2']['redirectURI']`.

How to achieve this?

Right now `jQuery('.dateField1').val(),jQuery('.dateField2').val()` take the values available when this object is parsed,the date field are datepicker whose value can vary.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know atleast

Comment: This is not a good question because it focuses on a very rare use case that only happens because you don't seem to have a proper understanding of the language constructs you're using. Which isn't a problem, because everyone has to start some place, but your question is also very obviously an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use functions. Don't forget to call them as functions (with "()" later).

```
{
  'element1': {
    'redirectURI': function() { return 'abc.php?toDate=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.dateField1').val());}
  },
  'element2': {
    'redirectURI': function() {return 'pqr.php?&toDate=' + encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.dateField2').val());}
  }
};
```

Comment: can these be made self invoking functions?

Comment: Do you mean recursive functions ?

Comment: I mean this way I will have to do `obj['element2']['redirectURI']()` to call this is that possible that I dont have to?callable with `obj['element2']['redirectURI']`

Comment: I don't think this is possible without explicit call to the function.

Comment: (function(){return 'hello'})() could be like that probably?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you make `redirectURI`  a function. So that you can do

`obj['element2']['redirectURI']()`

```
'element1':{'redirectURI' : function(){return 'abc.php?toDate='+encodeURIComponent(jQuery('.dateField1').val())}}
```

EDIT:
what i tried with self invoking as you asked in the comment

```
var obj = {
'element1':{'redirectURI' : (function(){return 'hello'})()}
};

console.log(obj['element1']['redirectURI']);
```

and its working in that case

Comment: can they be made self invoking functions??

Comment: i think so, i will modify the answer with what i tried

Comment: I think better to go with `obj['element2']['redirectURI']()`